# Defining a Boolean function on Haskell that determines if an element occurs once in a list

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to define a function in Haskell that if given an integer and a list of integers will give a 'true' or 'false' whether the integer occurs only once or not.

So far I've got:

> let once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool; once x l =

But I haven't finished writing the code yet. I'm very new to Haskell as you may be able to tell.

Answer (score 6):

Start off by using pattern matching:

```
once x [] =
once x (y:ys) =
```

This won't give you a good program immediately, but it will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: It's also often easier to tackle a more general problem.  I suggest that the OP defines `occursNTimes :: Eq a => Int -> a -> [a] -> Bool`?

Comment: @TomEllis For this case, I would even suggest that OP define a function `occurrences :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]` that finds every instance of the element in the list, then it's a simple matter to determine how many times it has occurred.

Comment: @TomEllis, that seems like overkill in this case. There's a Standard Prelude function that will fill out the definition I gave, but the OP could also write it.

Comment: @bheklilr: Sure, or even `count :: a -> [a] -> Int`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't use pattern matching explicitly. Instead, it keeps track of a `Bool` which represents if a occurance has already been found.

As others have pointed out, this is probably a homework problem, so I've intentionally left the `then` and `else` branches blank. I encourage user3482534 to experiment with this code and fill them in themselves.

```
once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
once a = foldr f False
    where f x b = if x == a then ??? else ???
```

**Edit**: The naive implementation I was originally thinking of was:

```
once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
once a = foldr f False
    where f x b = if x == a then b /= True else b
```

but this is incorrect as,

```
λ. once 'x' "xxx"
True
```

which should, of course, be `False` as `'x'` occurs more than exactly once.

However, to show that it is possible to write `once` using a fold, here's a revised version that uses a custom monoid to keep track of how many times the element has occured:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

data Occur = Zero | Once | Many         
    deriving Eq

instance Monoid Occur where           
    mempty = Zero                      
    Zero `mappend` x    = x         
    x    `mappend` Zero = x      
    _    `mappend` _    = Many 

once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
once a = (==) Once . foldMap f
    where f x = if x == a then Once else Zero

main = do                                
    let xss = inits "xxxxx"                        
    print $ map (once 'x') xss
```

which prints

```
[False,True,False,False,False]
```

as expected.

The structure of `once` is similar, but not identical, to the original.

Comment: I don't think this works. At least, if I understand the specification correctly, as True meaning that the element occurs *exactly* once.

Comment: No, this is not a fold at all. `foldr kons knil (x:xs) = kons x (foldr kons knil xs)`. The second argument to `kons` just doesn't give enough information to decide. It's possible to use a fold as an auxiliary function, but `once`, either in the exact or the at most sense, can't be defined directly as a fold.

Comment: This is not a fold over `Bool`. To use a fold you need at least a type with three values to represent 0,1,>=2 occurrences of `a`.

Comment: I just realized this has what could be considered an efficiency problem: it doesn't abort as soon as it sees a second copy. At first I thought the problem was just caused by the pattern matching in `mappend` being too strict, but that's not the (whole) problem: when the fold expands to `mappend Once whatever`, we only care whether `whatever` is `Zero` or not, but we are forced to calculate its exact value!

Comment: I *think* it can be fixed, however, by making `Occur` less monolithic. Something like a cleaned up version of `newtype Occur = Occur (Maybe Bool)`, with `zero = Occur Nothing`, `once = Occur (Just False)`, and `many = Occur (Just True)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this as if it were a homework question since it looks like one.

Read about pattern matching in function declarations, especially when they give an example of processing a list.  You'll use tools from [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html) later, but probably your professor is teaching about pattern matching.

Comment: Let us know if your prof wants you using `map`, `scan`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a function that maps values to a 1 or 0 depending on whethere there is a match ...

```
match :: a -> [a] -> [Int]
match x xs = map -- fill in the thing here such that
-- match 3 [1,2,3,4,5] == [0,0,1,0,0]
```

Note that there is the `sum` function that takes a list of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers in the list. So to count the matches a function can take the `match` function and return the counts.

```
countN :: a -> [a] -> Int
countN x xs = ? $ match x xs
```

And finally a function that exploits the `countN` function to check for a count of only 1. `(==1)`.

Hope you can figure out the rest ...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list and then check the length of the resulting list. If length == 1, you have only one occurrence of the given Integer:

```
once :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
once x = (== 1) . length . filter (== x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting generally, with `import Data.List (foldl')`, pointfree

```
count pred  =  foldl' (\ n x -> if pred x then n + 1 else n) 0
```

applicable like

```
count (< 10) [1 .. 10]  ==  9
count (== 'l') "Hello"  ==  2
```

gives

```
once pred xs  =  count pred xs == 1
```

---

Efficient O(n) short-circuit predicated form, testing whether the predicate is satisfied exactly once:

```
once :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
once pred list = one list 0
   where
      one []       1             = True
      one []       _             = False
      one _        2             = False
      one (x : xs) n | pred x    = one xs (n + 1)
                     | otherwise = one xs n
```

Or, using `any`:

```
none pred  =  not . any pred

once :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
once _    []                   = False
once pred (x : xs) | pred x    = none pred xs
                   | otherwise = one pred xs
```

gives

```
elemOnce y  =  once (== y)
```

which

```
elemOnce 47 [1,1,2]  ==  False
elemOnce 2 [1,1,2]  ==  True
elemOnce 81 [81,81,2]  ==  False
```